# CSS positioning issue. Creates a space between two divs.

Tags: html, css

My webpage can be found at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html. All the images and XHTML+CSS is there and can be accessed by anyone.

There is this blank space because of the uFlip image between the featured and the main content.

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while now with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Now I was suggested to extend my featured div till the end of the uFlip image, but my featured div background image size is already TOO big and I just cannot make it any more bigger.

Comment: Also adding position: absolute to the uFlip image seems to solve the blank space issue, but I'm sure it's not a good method of doing it as position absolute shows up weird in some browsers or devices

Comment: You would want be cautious when using `position:absolute` as it removes the element from the normal document flow; it no longer reserves any space in the layout computations.

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix: add `margin-top: -78px;` to `#main`.

To expand a bit... When you have elements that you wish to appear as if they span or "escape" containers, you have a few options. Among those are:

- Negative margins, either on the element itself, or on adjacent elements
- Absolute/Relative positioning using either negative values or positioning relative to a parent container
- Creating the appearance of containers that aren't really there by using background images or other css tricks

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a negative bottom margin to the uFlip image.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use position absolute why not crop the bottom of the image and then use a CSS background image on the next element that completes the uFlip image?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked in removing the white space:

```
#featured-image {
    margin-left: 98px;
    margin-top: -41px;
}
```

It works on FF7 but I'm not sure about other browsers.